# What causes an element to not respond to margin/padding?

Tags: html, css

Let's say I've got two elements, as pictured below, an img and a .date element. I've put a padding-top on the .date element, but it's just padding "inside" the img rather than being pushed off it. What would cause this? Is it the position of the img?

[image]

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: Can you give us a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)? Please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is the element set to `display:block`? Inline elements (span, a, i, strong etc) will not respond to margin or padding.

Comment: `display: inline-block` will also work.

Comment: So, in the four examples at http://jsfiddle.net/Q92UL/, why are the outcomes all different?

Comment: @Alohci ooh, nice one.